# Constructing a unified path analysis model from several datasets each with different combinations of variables

Tags: multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling, bic, path-model

I have four observational experiments (data sets) that I wish to combine and summarize in a single path analysis model.  Each experiment is 3-dimensional but the observables and therefore dimensions/variables are different in each data set.  One variable `X.1` is common to all datasets.  All other variables are present in exactly two experiments.

Here are the experiments and associated variables:

```
Experiment 1: {X.1, X.2, Y}
Experiment 2: {X.1, X.2, Z}
Experiment 3: {X.1, X.3, Y}
Experiment 4: {X.1, X.3, Z}
```

For the sake of my study, Y and Z are considered to be the dependent (response) variables in a set of multiple linear regression models (MLRs).

For each data set I minimized the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) to select the best MLR model.

These BIC-minimizing models (one for each experiment, same order as above) are as follows:

```
Y ~ X.1 + X.2
Z ~ X.1
Y ~ X.1 + X.3
Z ~ X.3
```

I am looking for a way to create a single path analysis model with two outputs, `Y` and `Z`, that unifies all four experiments.

Is there a smart way to get a single path analysis model out of this?

To make such a path model I believe I must first either 1) combine these separate MLR models OR 2) combine the datasets then make a single MLR model.  I'm not sure where to start for either of these methods.

Thank you for reading and offering advice.

BTW, there is a little bit of multicollinearity present in these MLR models, but the Variance Inflation Factor is less than 5 for all predictor variables.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this might be tricky. In path analysis you have one equation for each dependent. You can't do:

```
Y = a + b1X1 + b2X2 + b3X3
```

in your case because in experiment 1, b1 is the effect of X1 while holding X2 constant, and in experiment 3 b1 is the effect of X1 while holding X3 constant; b1 will probably be different in each case. Maybe better to just report 4 regression analyses.

Good luck!